# How to prevent a process from being disabled?

Tags: windows, task-manager

Within Task Manager we can disable and enable tasks and programs on Startup.  Is it possible to disable that function for custom apps/programs?

I was toying with Task Scheduler to test if the EVENT ID could trigger a restart...but it couldn't.

Comment: If your program or task runs as a service you can have recovery options for that. Check services.msc > Properties > Recovery

Answer (score -2):

Win 7

System Configuration Utility (Windows 7)

- Press Win-r. In the "Open:" field, type msconfig and press Enter.
- Click the Startup tab.
- Uncheck the items you do not want to launch on startup.

Win 8/10

- Navigate to the Task Manager.
- If necessary, click More details to see all of the tabs; select the Startup tab.
- Select the item not to launch at startup, and click Disable.

Comment: Your answer describes how to disable startup items. The OP is asking how to *disable* the ability of the user to disable startup items.